# Using pageBase with nightwatch.js

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to create an end-2-end test suite using nightwatch.js
I've looked around a bit and haven't really figured out how to use a pageBase, like is usually used when implementing POM.
I'm using the page_object that is built in to nightwatch, but can't seem to get it to use a pageBase.
Here is the code example.
To simplify things, let's say I have a common.js file, and a test.js file
I want test.js to inherit all of common.js commands and elements and implement some commands and elements of it's own, but I'm struggling with the syntax.

this is the common.js file

```js
let commonCommands = {

    clickOnMe: function () {
        return this.waitForElementVisible('@someElement', 2000)

    }

};




module.exports = {
    commands: [commonCommands],
    elements: {
        someElement: '#elementId'
    },
};
```

this is the test.js file

```js
const common = require('./common');

let testCommands = {
    doStuffFromTest: function () {
        return this;
    }

};

module.exports = {
    url: function () {
        return this.api.launch_url ;
    },
    commands: common.commands,

    elements: common.elements

};
```

How can I add commands and elements to the test.js ?

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't want to access those commands from your test, but rather from your other page objects. Since that's where all of your commands will be happening, common actions like clicking on an element or checking if something is present will be done at the page object level.